# Cannot properly position second inline-block element in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Cannot figure out, how to align "Add new item" button as well as "Search" control.
It's not ok only in Firefox, in other browsers the button is aligned to the top of outer container (it's a form).
Seems like in Firefox this button is aligned to baseline of the text in "Search" control - "Search text". But this information does not help me to resolve the isue, i've tried different approaches.

[image]

P.S. Please, do not suggest using float or absolute positioning - I cannot change design of our designer a lot.

CSS:

```
.localSearchWrapper {
  margin-right: 2em;
  max-width: 20em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.2em;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.9em;
}

.addNewItem {
  height: 2.8em;
  width: 2.8em;
  border: 3px solid #0E6463;
  background: #FFF url("/Content/images/plus.png") no-repeat scroll center center / 2em auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form ...>
  <div class="localSearchWrapper">
    <input name="localsearch" placeholder="Search text" id="localSearchField" type="search"></input>
    <input id="localSearchButton" type="button"></input>
  </div>
  <button class="addNewItem" type="button"></button>
  <!-- IE < 10 does not like giving a tbody a height. The workaround here applies the scrolling to a wrapped <div>. -->
  <!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <div class="old_ie_wrapper">
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <div style="overflow: hidden;" id="tableContainer" class="listContainer">...</div>    
  <!--[if lte IE 9]>
  </div>
  <!--<![endif]-->
</form>
```

[FIDDLE SOURCE](http://jsfiddle.net/8d2kgL8f/)

Comment: Why you are using `em` for positioning?

Comment: If you provide working snippet, someone could look at that and help you.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: @VladimirSerykh Well, i cannot answer this question, i'm not so much into those measurement units, i'm only a programmer trying it to look neat in FF, too. OK, i will try to arrange this in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You alter the vertical position of your search box so you need to do the same with your button.

Try adding

```
vertical-align: top;
position: relative;
top: -0.9em;
```

to your `.addNewItem`.

---

A better alternative would be to use a margin on the proper element and not try to adjust every element ad hoc.

Comment: Yeap, this seems OK, i think. There is some +/- 1 px discrepancies between browsers, but this is much better, than initially. Thanks. So I used the following hack in CSS: `@-moz-document url-prefix() {
 .addNewItem {
  vertical-align: top;
  top: -0.9em;
 }
}`